# When does the tangent bundle of a manifold admit a flat connection?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and let $TM$ denote its tangent bundle.  Under what conditions does $TM$ admit a flat connection $\omega$?

**Edit:**  Formerly, I asked about a flat connection on the frame bundle, but Deane Yang points out that a connection on the frame bundle is the same thing as one on the tangent bundle.  I am imposing no other assumptions on the manifold other than smoothness, and I am seeking what assumptions may obstruct the existence of a flat connection.

Comment: No other assumptions, right? No metric and no assumption on the torsion?

Comment: Also, note that a connection on the frame bundle is the same thing as a connection on the tangent bundle itself.

Comment: Deane: you're correct, I'm putting no other restrictions on the manifold.  Thanks for the tip, I'll edit the question to make it simpler.

Comment: A flat and torsion-free connection on the tangent bundle is also called an **affine structure**. The Levi-Civita connection of a Riemannian metric is always torsion-free.

Comment: One can find necessary conditions, e.g. the universal cover of $\mathcal{M}$ must be parallelisable. Sufficient conditions seem harder to come by...

Comment: Pulling back the connection to the universal cover gives a necessary condition: that the universal cover is parallelizable. But this is not sufficient (or if it is, a proof is not obvious.)

Comment: Actually, I was asking whether you were putting any other restriction on the connection, not the manifold. You're not requiring the connection to be torsion free or the connection of a Riemannian or semi-Riemannian metric, right?

Comment: Very insightful, Will ;)

Comment: I am almost certain that no one knows, even if we restrict to compact manifolds.

Comment: The double torus (or any closed surface of higher genus) seems to be an example of a manifold whose universal cover is parallelisable but which admits no flat connection.

Comment: One can turn this into an obstruction theory question by asking whether the map $M\to BGL(n,R)$ classifying the tangent bundle lifts to $BGL(n,R)^d$, where $GL(n,R)^d$ denotes $GL(n,R)$ with the discrete topology. Thus the obstructions lie in 
$H^k(M;\pi_{i-1}(F))$ where $F$ denotes the homotopy fiber. 
This is a really complicated space in general. 

Comment: (cont) When $n=2$ and $M$ is oriented, then (passing from $GL(n)$ to $SO(n)$) $BSO(2)^d=K(R/Z,1)$ and $BSO(2)=K(Z,2)$, so that the only obstruction is that the euler class of $M$ $e\in H^2(M;Z)$ lifts to  $H^1(M;R/Z)$, or equivalently vanishes in $H^2(M;R)$, which is true only for the torus.

Comment: When n=3 and the manifold is orientable, it always does (orientable three manifolds are parallelisable)

Comment: Interestingly, while for $g \neq 1$, a closed orientable surface $\Sigma_g$ of genus $g$ does not admit a flat connection, the product $S^1 \times \Sigma_g$ always does; in fact, the proof I know of this fact (due to Benzecri) endows $S^1 \times \Sigma_g$ with an affine structure, i.e. with a flat and torsion-free connection.

Comment: @Deane:  I'm so used to working with Riemannian connections that I hadn't thought about torsion in general.  For this question, I would ideally like the connection to be both flat and torsion-free, though I need no Riemannian assumptions. I can see from the answers and comments so far that the existence of such connections is extremely non-trivial.  This is one of those cases where the realization that a question is hard is far more satisfying than having any particular answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The question of existence of flat connection on tangent bundles of manifolds was studied quite extensively. Milnor proved in one of his early papers that surfaces (compact without boundary) of non-zero Euler characteristic don't admit such a connection. A result of Smillie can be used to rule out existence of flat connection on tangent bundles of many even dimensional manifolds; a manifold $M^n$ that admit such a connection should satisfy the condition $|\chi(M^n)|\le \frac{||M^n||}{2^n}$, where $||M^n||$ denotes the simplicial norm of $M^n$. You can check  http://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/PDF/4[35].pdf , page 229 for a short proof. Also, Smillie constructed examples of manifolds of non-zero Euler characteristics that admit flat connection on their tangent bundle:  http://www.springerlink.com/content/g6804q4u77327887/

The following recent article of Goldman will be relevant *Milnor's seminal work on flat manifolds and bundles* http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0216

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.

Comment: The link to `www.ihes.fr` also seems to be broken, but the article is available at [Numdam](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1982__56__5_0 "zbMATH review at https://zbmath.org/0516.53046").

Answer (score 12):

If a vector bundle admits a flat connection, then the rational Pontryagin classes of the tangent bundle vanish (as follows from Chern-Weil theory, see Milnor-Stasheff's "Characteristic classes", Appendix C, or Kobayashi-Nomidzu, volume 2). So in a sense most vector bundles do not admit flat connections.

Answer (score 1):

Is the connection supposed to be torsion free? Otherwise I think any parralelizable manifold admits a flat connection in the tangent bundle. If you require the connection to be torsion free than one obstruction is that the manifold has to have the Euler characteristic zero. This is a conjecture of Chern proven in dimension n=2.