# Does every manifold have a flat connection?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Suppose I have a manifold and a vector bundle over it, but not a connection or a metric. Can I always find a connection on it that has a Riemann curvature tensor that is identically zero? If so, can I always find a connection that has both Riemann curvature and torsion tensors identically zero?

I've attempted to simply for the Christoffel symbols, but couldn't make headway in the equations.

Comment: Your question needs some edition because it is very imprecise. (E.g.a connection is defined on a vector bundle, not on a manifold.) In any case, if the manifold  is compact, oriented and the Euler characteristic is $\neq 0$, then there cannot exist any metric on the tangent bundle   and connection compatible with it whose curvature is zero. This is a consequence of the Gauss-Bonnet-Chern theorem.

Comment: Since you are working without a metric, you can take the zero-connection on any vector bundle over your manifold. Its curvature is certainly zero (ie. the connection is flat).

Comment: Very close question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/91852/when-does-the-tangent-bundle-of-a-manifold-admit-a-flat-connection#comment236076_91852

Comment: @Peter, there isn't a zero connection. Unless you mean something perculiar? Either way, your conclusion isn't right.

Comment: The answer is no, as Liviu points out. The lowest-dimensional example is the tangent bundle of $S^2$, by Gauss-Bonnet.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the "exterior derivative" connection on a trivial bundle over the manifold. When studying connections on trivial bundles, one often takes it to be the origin of the space of connections. This connection is definitely flat, though.

Comment: Also, Riemann curvature tensor makes no sense for arbitrary vector bundles.

Comment: @Misha, why not? There is a well-defined two-form with values in the adjoint bundle.

Comment: Peter, on a general non-trivial bundle "the exterior derivative connection" may not exist, not even make sense. This is what Paul is referring to. It exists locally after a choice of local trivialization, but not in general globally.

Comment: Yes, this is true. Indeed, you will find that I only referred to the exterior derivative connection on a trivial bundle.

Comment: @PaulReynolds: Yes, there is a notion of connections and curvature for vector bundles, but it is no longer Riemann's (and is no longer a tensor) and should not be referred to by this name, as Riemann curvature tensor is something much more specific.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Milnor proved in [On the existence of a connection with curvature zero, Comm. Math. Helv. v 32] that bundles over a surface of genus g has flat connections iff its Euler class is less than g by an absolute value (see also Wood, Bundles with totally disconnected structure group). Sullivan in "A generalization of Milnor's inequality ...Comm. Math. Helv. v. 51" find a finite upper bound for the Euler class of a R^n-bundle with the affine connection over manifold M^n (the number of n-simplices in the triangulation of M^n). Hope, this might help.

Answer (score 13):

By [Chern-Weil theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Weil_homomorphism), the real [Pontryagin classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_class) $p_k \in H^{4k}(X, \mathbb{R})$ of a real vector bundle $V$ on a smooth manifold $X$ are determined by the curvature form of any connection on that bundle; in particular, if the curvature vanishes, then so do all of the $p_k$. Hence if any of the $p_k$ don't vanish, then $V$ does not admit a flat connection. (Note that all of the $p_k$ vanish if $\dim X \le 3$; Milnor's result regarding the case $\dim X = 2$ requires more difficult tools.)

If $V$ is taken to be the tangent bundle of $X$, then the first case where this happens is when $\dim X = 4$, where $p_1 \in H^4(X, \mathbb{R})$. If $X$ is closed and orientable then $p_1$ is nonzero iff $X$ has nonzero [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(topology)), by the [Hirzebruch signature theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_of_a_multiplicative_sequence#L_genus_and_the_Hirzebruch_signature_theorem). The simplest example of a $4$-manifold with nonzero signature is $\mathbb{CP}^2$; it follows that the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ does not admit a flat connection.

Comment: You have 666 answers...