# Are there always flat connections?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology

Let $G$ be a simply connected Lie group and $\Gamma$ a cocompact discrete and torsion-free subgroup. Is there a (real or complex) smooth vector bundle $E$ over the manifold $G/\Gamma$, which does not admit a flat connection?

Comment: You may be missing some hypotheses.  Otherwise, there are very simple examples provided by smooth complex line bundles with nontrivial first Chern class over $\mathbb{T}^2 = \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: Can you give me a reference as to why non-vanishing of the chern class implies non-flatness?

Comment: Chern classes are computed in terms of curvature of any connection. A flat connection has zero Chern classes. See Chern, *Vector bundles with a connection,* **Global Differential Geometry**.

Comment: I think this [old answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/91880) is general enough to addresses also this question. Is it not?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine:  The OP has not asked that $E$ be the tangent bundle of $G/\Gamma$.  Indeed, the tangent bundle of $G/\Gamma$ *is* trivial, so it *does* have a flat connection.

Comment: @RobertBryant That older question was different, of course. But the linked answer was phrased to apply to any vector bundle (along the same lines as the comments by Ben McKay and yourself, with a couple of different references).

Comment: @IgorKhavkine:  However, that answer has something wrong with it.  The statement 'If a vector bundle admits a flat connection, then the rational Pontryagin classes of the tangent bundle vanish..." is just false.  I suspect that I.B. meant to start with "If a *tangent* bundle admits a flat connection...", which would have been a true statement.  Also, the final statement that 'most vector bundles don't admit a flat connection' is true, but that says nothing about the vector bundles over particular manifolds, such as $G/\Gamma$.

Comment: @RobertBryant I may be out of my depth here, but it seems to me that I.B.'s answer also works if you just replace "tangent bundle" by "vector bundle" (which is how I had read it). Anyway, this type of question seems to come up often enough that it might be worth recording an answer of sufficient generality to be useful in the future. I've opened a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/455423) to give someone an opportunity to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so there'll be an answer:  Whether every vector bundle over $G/\Gamma$ admits a flat connection depends on the group $G$ and the subgroup $\Gamma$.

For example, if $G=\mathrm{SU}(2)\simeq S^3$ and $\Gamma = \{e\}$, then, since every (real or complex) vector bundle over $G/\Gamma \simeq S^3$ is trivial (because $\pi_2(H)=0$ for any Lie group $H$ (see Steenrod's *Topology of Fibre Bundles*, Corollary 18.6), it follows, *a fortiori* that every vector bundle $E$ over $G/\Gamma \simeq S^3$ has a flat connection.

Meanwhile, if $G=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\Gamma = \mathbb{Z}^2\subset G$, we know that the isomorphism classes of complex line bundles over $G/\Gamma=\mathbb{T}^2$ are parametrized by the elements of $H^2(\mathbb{T}^2,\mathbb{Z})\simeq \mathbb{Z}$, and the curvature of a connection for such a line bundle can only be identically zero for the line bundle that represents $0\in H^2(\mathbb{T}^2,\mathbb{Z})$.  Thus, none of the other complex line bundles can have a connection with vanishing curvature.